# Columns in a TableRow divided using weights & weightsums not spacing elements properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, tablerow, android-layout-weight

I've been assigned to create an activity that displays table of changes made to the app by version. The table has four columns, Id, Type, Description, and Version.

To do this, I placed a TableLayout in a scrollView. Then, I have a template for the TableRows, that are inflated dynamically at Runtime. The column widths should stay static; they can overflow in height but not width.

To achieve this, I tried using the weight & weight: sum property of the column and row container respectively. I have set the `layout_width` to `0` on both.

The problem is that the columns are expanding outside the screen boundaries. I would post the images but I don't have the authority.

(Landscape looks close but you can see that the outer boundry is still being cut off).

I noticed that in if the weights of the children add to about 45% of the total then the weighting comes close to looking right.

Finally, the views separating the columns have been given a weight of zero, and 1dip width. (I'm not sure if that could be causing a problem).

To me it looks like that weighting is using the width as if it was in landscape mode. Do I have to make two layouts, one for portrait, and one for landscape?

I've added the XML layout for the table row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_row_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/top_border"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_id"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Id" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_type"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Type" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_weight="2"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view4"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_version"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Version" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view6"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

The upper and lower view are top and bottom borders.

And here is the layout for the table that its getting added too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/view_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:shrinkColumns="0"
            android:stretchColumns="0" >
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add your row layout for reference? Also, I'd double check again if the sum of the individual weights really doesn't exceed the value specified in [`android:weightSum`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) (I'm assuming you made a typo when referring to this attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks MH.

Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.  (I'm new to Android and Stack Overflow...and I didn't realize that you answered my questsion.)  I've added the row layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_row_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/top_border"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_id"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Id" android:textSize="10sp"       android:layout_weight="0.20"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_type"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Type" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view4"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_version"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Version" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view6"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_weight="0.01"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

David