# Adding row with 2 columns to Android table layout - 2nd column invisible

Tags: android

I add columns to an android table layout in this way:

```
public void addWebAction(TableLayout table){
    TableRow rowWeb = new TableRow(this);
    rowWeb.setWeightSum(1f);

    TextView tvWeb = new TextView(this);
    tvWeb.setTextSize(18);
    tvWeb.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
    tvWeb.setText(contact.getWeb());
    TableRow.LayoutParams trlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.8f);
    tvWeb.setLayoutParams(trlp);
    rowWeb.addView(tvWeb);

    ImageButton ibWeb = new ImageButton(this);
    ibWeb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    ibWeb.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    ibWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(contact.getWeb()));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });

    trlp.weight = 0.1f;
    ibWeb.setLayoutParams(trlp);
    rowWeb.addView(ibWeb);

    ImageButton abWeb = new ImageButton(this);
    abWeb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    abWeb.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_chat);
    abWeb.setLayoutParams(trlp);
    rowWeb.addView(abWeb);

    table.addView(rowWeb);
}
```

The problem is: If the textview contains a long string the 2nd column is moved out of the screen. In which way did I have to add TableRow Parameters to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give weightSum to table layout and divide edittexts weights two.
You can see the simple example in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590974/3098590

Comment: Hi, I've edited my source code above. My problem is, that all columns have the same size (the first on is shrinked but it should have an 8/10 size). Which parameter is wrong?

Comment: if the first have an 8/10,the second must have 2/10.I think you give all weight 0.8f.

Comment: Why all 0.8f? - This don't work. I want this: |Text 80%|Button 10%|Button 10%| . I've set the weightSum of the row to 1f and the weight of the Textview to 0.8f. So if I set the weight of the ImageButtons to 0.1f it should work, or?